# SSIS Upgrade Results in Empty 'VstaProjects' Solution for Script Componets

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, ssis, upgrade

In the transition from using VS2008 to VS2010 for SSIS packages a large portion of my script components have broken.  When I open a script component and select "Edit Script" the VSTA editor appears, but contains 0 projects in the solution.

This problem occurs for only about half of the packages that were upgraded, and in some cases half of the script componets will load in one package and the other half will not.  I have not yet been able to determine a commonality that could be the cause.

Any help that could lead to a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Below are screenshots of what I'm seeing in the solution explorer and what I'm expecting to see to help illustrate the issue.

Problem:

[image: Problem]

Expecting:

[image: Expecting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I deleted all COM object references from the old packages before upgrading them and it worked.